# SwiftUI: KFImage, aspectRatio(), and layoutPriority()

Tags: swiftui, kingfisher

I’m having some issues with [`KFImage`](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher). It works fine with the placeholder image, until the remote image is loaded. It seems to be some interaction between `.aspectRatio()` and `.layoutPriority(-1)`.

I have a kind of card with an image, and a couple text blocks beneath it. I want the image to be clipped to a view that has a specific aspect ratio, and whose width is dictated by the container (in the real app these live in a grid, and size will vary from device to device. I want the image to grow, rather than the spacing to grow).

Here’s what I get with the placeholder (the bubbles) and the loaded image (the aspect ratio test image). The placeholder image is 654 x 768, and the loaded image is 1080 x 1920. The aspect ratio of the placeholder is properly maintained, and it is clipped to the desired aspect ratio.

[image: SwiftUI preview of proper placeholder behavior, but incorrect loaded image.]

But as you can see, the loaded image is scaled non-uniformly to fit in the same aspect-ratio as the placeholder. The normal solution to that is to add `.aspectRatio(.fill)`. But if I do that on `KFImage`, it blows up everything:

[image: SwiftUI preview after adding .aspectRatio, both images displayed incorrectly.]

Here’s the code. Note the `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` on `KFImage` is commented out. If you uncomment it, you get the second image above.

```swift
import SwiftUI

import Kingfisher


struct
SellerShowCell: View
{
    let     title           :   String
    let     secondary       :   String?
    var     startTime       :   Date?           =   nil
    var     thumbnailURL    :   URL?            =   nil
    
    var
    body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0.0) {
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                //  Thumbnail background…
                
                ZStack {
                    KFImage(self.thumbnailURL)
                        .cancelOnDisappear(true)
                        .placeholder {
                            ZStack {
                                Color(.black)
                                Image("image_placeholder_background")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .layoutPriority(-1)
                            }
                        }
                    .resizable()
//                  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) //  Uncommenting this ruins the placeholder and allows the loaded image to dictate the parent size
//                  .layoutPriority(-1)              //  This does not have any obvious effect on KFImage
                }
                .aspectRatio(158.0 / 220.0, contentMode: .fit)
                .cornerRadius(16.0)
                
                Text("A Note")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(8.0)
                    .background(Color.purple)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .padding([.top, .leading], 10.0)
            }
            
            //  Title…
            
            Text("\(self.title)")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .lineLimit(2)
                .font(.custom("Helvetica", size: 16.0).weight(.semibold))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(.top, 12.0)
            
            //  Secondary…
            
            if let secondary = self.secondary {
                Text("\(secondary)")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .font(.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 12.0).weight(.medium))
                    .foregroundColor(Color("secondary-color"))
                    .padding(.top, 12.0)
            }
        }
        .border(Color.green)
    }
}

struct SellerShowCell_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("main-tab-background")
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack(spacing: 20.0) {
                SellerShowCell(title: "Here is a caption of sufficient length to be a couple of lines",
                                secondary: "Secondary Text",
                                thumbnailURL: nil)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 80)
                SellerShowCell(title: "Here is a caption of sufficient length to be a couple of lines",
                                secondary: "Secondary Text",
                                thumbnailURL: URL(string: "https://i.imgur.com/iH7Xe20.jpg")!)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 80)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but I recommend not making a new line between `if`/`VStack`/whatever and the opening bracket (`{`). Just a bit easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: @aheze I actually disagree about being easier to read, but I'll grant that a lot of people seem to prefer more compact code. I personally hate having the opening brace on the same line, except in rare circumstances (when the whole block is on one line).

Comment: Fair enough. Although note that Apple uses the same-line style (see [`Form`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form) for example).

Comment: Yup. I worked at Apple for several years. They're wrong. 

Comment: There you go, mangled it for you.

Comment: @Rick have you solved the issue, can u update your solution here

Comment: @Jin I'm sorry. I left that company a while back and can’t look at the code now. I don't remember how I solved the issue.